# how can i change this picture? i hope create html sitemap

Tags: html, css

i can't make it .
please help me !

```
before -> after
```

how can i change this picture? i hope create html sitemap

[image]

this is my code

```
<div class="sitemapcontainer">
<h1>Sitemap</h1>

<ul>
<li clas



<style>
.sitemapcontainer {max-width:1200px; width:100%; max-height:430px; height:100%;}
.sitemapcontainer ul {list-style-type:none;display:block;max-width:151px;width:100%;}
.lili {float:left; font-size:14px; border-bottom:1px solid #E7E7E7;width:100%; text-align:center; background-color:#F1F1F1;max-width:151px;width:100%;}
.lititle {text-align:center; background-color:#05508b;color:#ffffff;border-right:1px ;solid #ffffff;max-width:151px;width:100%;}
.lititle a {color:#ffffff;}
.litltle a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#be1c21;}
</style>
```

Comment: Which picture? Its totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following css:

```
.sitemapcontainer ul {
   float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xw7e4avb/1/)

---

Use this Plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/v2/ if you want to adjust automatically.

Comment: This does not work if the columns does not have an equal height. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/xw7e4avb/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use CSS3 columns. And it works in most browsers, including IE 10+.

```
.sitemapcontainer{
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 4;
}
```

For older browsers you can use a polyfill, such as:
https://github.com/hamsterbacke23/multicolumn-polyfill